# how tell to webpack to use plugin or loader only for specific file?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader, html-webpack-plugin

I want to force the webpack to enable specific plugin or loader for certain file/folder, multiply files. Is there a way?

Comment: Can you elaborate more with, for example, an example on what you mean with "specific plugin or loader for certain file/folders"?

Note that in order to get great answers, you should look into [how to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use "include" to only include a specific folder for this rule. For example (this code only compile .ts files in /app/src folder)

```
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'react-hot-loader/webpack' },
                { loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' }
            ],
            include: resolve(__dirname, './../app/src')
        },
```

More examples here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition

Comment: I have another problem. i have tried to use https://github.com/petehunt/we... async-loading with require-ensure , as replacement for my < script src='path to js'> . But now build fails with 'ERROR in ./~/file-loader?emitFile=false!./path/to/myfile.js Module build failed: SyntaxError: Deleting local variable in strict mode' . but i have not 'use strict' in this .js file. I have searched for some 'disable use strict' plugins , but still unsuccessful

Comment: i have angular template and <script src='_my js file'>.. and i want to load it with webpack , not through <script src='required js'> . i need it for work with electron app, becouse it cant take statis js, becouse its withous server

Comment: This is an answer for loaders, but how about plugins?